# Making Sidebar with material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i'm learning material-ui by making the right navigation menu like this one: http://demo.geekslabs.com/materialize/v3.1/ or least like this: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar

I'm using Drawer to make my sidebar, the problem is when the sidebar is toggled, it hides the content on the right. I want when my sidebar is toggled, it took place and push the content to the right and both sidebar and content got their own scrollbar. Here is my current code:

Sidebar.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import lightBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';

export default class Sidebar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {open: false};
    }

    handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});

    handleClose = () => this.setState({open: false});

    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(lightBaseTheme)}>
                <div>
                    <RaisedButton
                        label="Open Drawer"
                        onTouchTap={this.handleToggle}
                    />
                    <Drawer
                        containerStyle={{height: 'calc(100% - 64px)', top: 64}}
                        docked={true}
                        width={200}
                        open={this.state.open}
                        onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})
                        }
                    >
                        <AppBar title="AppBar" />
                        <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.handleClose}>Menu Item</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.handleClose}>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
                    </Drawer>
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

My Layout.js:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import s from './Layout.css';
import Header from '../Header';
import Feedback from '../Feedback';
import Footer from '../Footer';
import Sidebar from '../Sidebar';

import lightBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();

function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(lightBaseTheme)}>
            <AppBar title="My web" />
        </MuiThemeProvider>

      <Sidebar/>
      {React.Children.only(children)}
      <Feedback />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(s)(Layout);
```

Comment: I have the same question, I also want to push the content to the right when the drawer is opened.

Comment: I find have an answer to this here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620302/how-to-get-material-ui-drawer-to-squeeze-other-content-when-open/40640154#40640154 ---- By Jeff McCloud

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is by design. "Material Design", that is :)

https://material.io/archive/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

What you're asking for would no longer be a drawer, as described by the Material Design spec. Material-ui attempts to follow that spec faithfully.

You will probably have to create your own component, because I don't think you'll be able to sufficiently manipulate the markup and inline CSS rendered by the Drawer component to accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: Link is dead. This is the correct answer now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49352306/550198

Answer (score 13):

This can be accomplished with the new version of Material-UI.

Check [this demos](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#persistent-drawer) out.

The behavior is described in the [Material specification](https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer) under the "Persistent" heading.

The mentioned version of Material-UI is `v1.0.0-beta.38`. So far I noticed it very stable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if Material Design has changed since this was posted but I think OP is describing "Persistent" Drawer which is defined in the spec. Look under "Behavior". However, material-ui doesn't provide a persistent drawer.

Here's a decent work around using the current material-ui drawer by pushing the content to the right the same width as the drawer.

[How to get Material-UI Drawer to 'squeeze' other content when open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620302/how-to-get-material-ui-drawer-to-squeeze-other-content-when-open/40640154#40640154)